# Jmeter error - "error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"

Tags: rest, api, jmeter, salesforce

I was trying to setup Jmeter for Salesforce API testing. However getting the below error during Salesforce authorization:

> "error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not
>   supported"

I am passing the parameters as in the screenshots attached. The same parameters when passed in Postman works fine, however I am getting this error in Jmeter. Please let me know if I am making some error in passing the parameters in Jmeter.

[Jmeter_HTTP Header Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAF8H.jpg)

[Jmeter_HTTP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mV4n.jpg)

[Jmeter_Sampler Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYCKq.jpg)

Comment: Try removing Content-Type parameter

Answer (score 0):

According to [HTTP Status Code 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) documentation

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Looking into your request, you're sending [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header as `application/json` therefore your server expects [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and you're providing something different.

My expectation is that you should switch to `Body Data` tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and set the request body to look like:

[image]

Check out [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article for more information on REST APIs testing using JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with the same issue but it finally worked for me by doing the following:

1. Use Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded in an HTTP Header Manager
2. Make sure is a POST Method and that you're using https
3. Not sure if it is necessary but in the Parameters tab make sure all (grant_type, password, client_secret_ client_id and username) are Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded and check the URL Encode option for all
4. Only check "Follow Redirects" and "Use KeepAlive" options in the HTTP Request

hope it works for you too